# React Native meta appearances crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, react-native-ui-kitten

I am very new to React Native, but I have successfully made a little app that just consists of 2 different screens using `react-navigation` library.

My problem is that my App wont load when I try to use the UI library UI-Kitten. I'm positive that there's not anything wrong with the library but rather with my code.

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mapping, light as lightTheme } from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider, Layout, Text, Button } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { fadeIn, fromTop, fromBottom, zoomIn, zoomOut } from 'react-navigation-transitions';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title='Back home'
          color='white'
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
        header: null
      },
    },
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Details',
        header: null
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    transitionConfig: () => zoomIn(),
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

And this outputs this error when trying to launch:
https://pastebin.com/ygWFcgD0 (Long)

Thank you for ANY help or input on this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't configured the UI library correctly. The setup is outlined [in the documentation](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten#quick-start).
Namely, see the `mapping` and `theme` props, as well the use of `ApplicationProvider`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mapping, light as lightTheme } from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { Application } from './path-to/application.component';

export default App = () => (
  <ApplicationProvider 
    mapping={mapping}
    theme={lightTheme}
    <Application/>
  </ApplicationProvider>
);
```

Comment: I don't understand the 4th import, I only have the App.js, what am I supposed to reference to here?

Comment: @javgogel It is a sample import if you structure your application logic separately from bootstrapping. In your case it would be your `AppContainer` without an import.

Comment: So I just skip that line completely?